# Preprocessor double hash (##) operator, how to concatenate variable value

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

Here is a short program I wrote

```
#include <iostream>
#define test0 "abc"
#define test1 "def"
#define concat(x,y) x##y
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i)
      std::cout << concat(test,i) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't compile (it concatenates `i` instead of `i` value), is there a way I can concatenate `i`'s values instead of `i`'s name?

> test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>       test1.cpp:8:1: error: ‘testi’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Macros and other preprocessor stuff all happen at *compile-time*, so this is never going to do what you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

No. Macros are expanded before compilation (hence the term **pre**-processor), and can only manipulate the tokens that appear in the source code. The value of the variable isn't known until the program is run.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The preprocessor (the part of the compiler that handles `#define` and `#include`) runs *before* any other compiler pass, and long before the program ever runs. The variable `i` will not have a value until the program runs.

Keep in mind that the preprocessor is little more than a text-replace tool for your program source code.

Comment: Technically, the compiler does a couple of other things first, but it's close enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833524/what-are-the-stages-of-compilation-of-a-c-program

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I didn't want to get bogged down in character set conversions and tokenization.